# Magento DOMPDF autoloading iisue

Tags: php, magento, autoload, dompdf

I see following entries in my log file:

```
    2013-08-28T17:45:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(DOMPDF.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/site/site.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
    2013-08-28T17:45:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(DOMPDF.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/site/site.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
    2013-08-28T17:45:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening 'DOMPDF.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/site/site.com/app/code/local:/home/site/site.com/app/code/community:/home/site/site.com/app/code/core:/home/site/site.com/lib:.:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php5/lib/pear')  in /home/site/site.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
    2013-08-28T17:45:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Stylesheet.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/site/site.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
    2013-08-28T17:45:09+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Stylesheet.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/site/site.com/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

What could be the reason that DOMPDF_autoload function is not executed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The file `DOMPDF.php` is not part of any standard Magento installation.  It appears you, or someone working on your system, has injected some custom code into your Magento system.

Somewhere in this custom code, there's a line that looks something like this

```
$objet = new DOMPDF;
```

Since this DOMPDF object hasn't been defined, PHP tries to run it through it's autoloader.  The autoloader for Magento classes is "first" on the queue, and treats DOMPDF like is was a Magento class.

This means trying to include the file `DOMPDF.php`.  Since this class **isn't** a Magento class, the autoloader fails.  Magento's autoloader doesn't fail gracefully, and you get the errors you see.

You'll need to make sure you're including all the files in [DOMPDF](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) correctly.  There's myriad ways to do this — I'd contact the developer who did the initial work, or the developer who built the extension, and have them document how they included this library.

Comment: Thanks Alan. You pointed me to right direction. This is library used by Ip/Pdffree extension.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing /lib/dompdf6/include/autoload.inc.php. Content of this file is:

```
    function DOMPDF_autoload($class) {
      $filename = DOMPDF_INC_DIR . "/" . mb_strtolower($class) . ".cls.php";

      if ( is_file($filename) )
        require_once($filename);
    }
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
```

This blog post was very helpful.
http://sim.plified.com/2010/11/17/make-dompdf-work-with-magento/

Please note that code runs on PHP Version 5.3.13.

Comment: Which version of dompdf? The full content of the current autoload.inc.php is much larger: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/include/autoload.inc.php